# Unable to filter get-wmiobject based on InstalledOn

Tags: windows, powershell

My requirement is to get all the latest updates installed in my system. "get-wmiobject" gives me the data of all updates installed in my system. The code I have written here is

Method 1:

```
$y = get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering | sort-object -Property InstalledOn -Descending | select-object -Property * -First 1
$x = Get-Date $y.InstalledOn
Write-Host $x
get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering -Filter "InstalledOn='$x'"
```

Method 2:

```
$y = get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering | sort-object -Property InstalledOn -Descending | select-object -Property * -First 1
$z = $y.InstalledOn
Write-Host $z
get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering -Filter "InstalledOn='$z'"
```

All these are giving me empty output. 
All these will work with filtering strings, but is not working with date filtering. 
What is wrong here?

However below code is working:

```
$y = get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering | sort-object -Property InstalledOn -Descending | select-object -Property * -First 1
get-wmiobject -class win32_quickfixengineering | Where-Object {$_.InstalledOn -eq $y.InstalledOn}
```

I would like to know why the filter is not working.

Comment: [1] in `method 1` - where is `$z` coming from? as it stands, your code will error out since the date in `$x` will not work correctly. [2] in that same code block, what is the purpose of `$y`? it seems to just be getting the newest QFE item ... and you never seem to use it.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, Thanks for your reply. Right, method 1 was giving error. I corrected it.

Comment: please look over my Answer. i think it gives you a workaround for what you want to achieve. i don't know why the filter will not work, tho. [*blush*]

Comment: Where-object worked, but filter is not. It is working with string inputs. :P

Comment: i suspect that there is a ... peculiarity ... in how the WQL filter works with that property. i can't find any hint concerning what the oddity is, tho.

Comment: also, your final code sample runs the same CIM/WMI query _twice_. there is no need for that. look at may Answer for how to just run the query once & reuse the data as needed. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know why the `-Filter` you try to use is not working. i cannot make it work at all. presumably, the QueryLanguage used has some oddity that is not clearly documented. [*sigh ...*]

however, if all you want is the QFE items that were applied on the last day in the QFE list, the following works ... [*grin*]

- uses `Get-HotFix` instead of the CIM/WMi calls
  this is no faster, but it seems more powershell-ish.
- sorts by the `InstalledOn` property with newest 1st
- groups by that prop
- selects the 1st group
- grabs the `.Group` value from that group
- assigns it to `$NewestQFE_Group`
- shows it on screen

the code ...

```
$NewestQFE_Group = (Get-HotFix |
    Sort-Object -Descending -Property 'InstalledOn' |
    Group-Object -Property 'InstalledOn')[0].Group

$NewestQFE_Group
```

output [yes, i am on win7 still [*grin*]] ...

```
Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn              
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------              
MySysName     Security Update  KB4534310     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  2020-01-15 12:00:00 AM   
MySysName     Security Update  KB4536952     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  2020-01-15 12:00:00 AM   
MySysName     Update           KB4532945     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  2020-01-15 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: InstalledOn is a ScriptProperty.

Comment: @js2010 - ah! thank you for the info! i was oh-so-curious about that ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Installedon is a scriptproperty, that converts the original string, like '8/2/2019', to a datetime object.  The original string wouldn't be good for sorting.

```
$a = get-wmiobject win32_quickfixengineering | select -last 1


$a | gm installedon | fl *

TypeName   : System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_QuickFixEngineering
Name       : InstalledOn
MemberType : ScriptProperty
Definition : System.Object InstalledOn {get=if ([environment]::osversion.version.build -ge 7000)
                       {
                       # WMI team fixed the formatting issue related to InstalledOn
                       # property in Windows7 (to return string)..so returning the WMI's
                       # version directly
                        [DateTime]::Parse($this.psBase.properties["InstalledOn"].Value,
             [System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo]::new())
                       }
                       else
                       {
                       $orig = $this.psBase.properties["InstalledOn"].Value
                       $date = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUTC($("0x" + $orig))
                       if ($date -lt "1/1/1980")
                       {
                       if ($orig -match "([0-9]{4})([01][0-9])([012][0-9])")
                       {
                       new-object datetime @([int]$matches[1], [int]$matches[2], [int]$matches[3])
                       }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                       $date
                       }
                       };}



$a.psbase.properties['installedon'].value

8/2/2019


get-wmiobject win32_quickfixengineering -filter "installedon='8/2/2019'"

Source        Description      HotFixID      InstalledBy          InstalledOn
------        -----------      --------      -----------          -----------
DESKTOP-JQ... Security Update  KB4493470     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM  8/2/2019 12:00:00 AM
```